# transition animation problem in flutter when using TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

My transition animation doesn't apply to pages that have TextField.
when I remove TextField the animation works properly.
anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you add some code pls ?

Comment: without code cant get any idea

Comment: @BabC I added the code in the answer

Comment: @JanviPatel see the answer

Comment: Is a Flutter problem. There is an open issue in GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75973

Answer (score 0):

this is my slider animation:

```
class SlideLeftRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SlideLeftRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(1, 0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        ),
  );
}
```

this is my page:

```
class VerifyAuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String phone;
  final int expTime;

  VerifyAuthPage({Key key, @required this.phone, @required this.expTime});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Container(color: Colors.red,

           child: TextField(),

      ),);
  }
```

this is my root app:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: BanijetColors.PRIMARY,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'IranSanse',
        primaryColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Splash(),
      initialRoute: 'splash',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings setting) {
        return mapNamesToRoutes(setting);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is mapNamesToRoute function:

```
SlideLeftRoute mapNamesToRoutes(RouteSettings setting) {
  Widget destination;

  final requestAuthCubit = sl<RequestAuthCubit>();
  final verifyAuthCubit = sl<VerifyAuthCubit>();

  switch (setting.name) {
    case 'splash':
      destination = Splash();
      break;
    case 'auth/request':
      destination = MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => InputValidationCubit(
                inputType: InputType.Phone,
                inputValidator: sl<InputValidator>())),
        BlocProvider.value(value: requestAuthCubit)
      ], child: RequestAuthPage());

      break;

    case 'auth/verify':
      final Map<String, Object> bundle = setting.arguments;
      destination = MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => InputValidationCubit(
                inputType: InputType.VerificationCode,
                inputValidator: sl<InputValidator>())),
        BlocProvider.value(value: requestAuthCubit),
        BlocProvider.value(value: verifyAuthCubit),
        BlocProvider.value(value: sl<TimerCubit>()),
      ], child: VerifyAuthPage(phone: bundle['phone'], expTime: bundle['exp']));
      break;
    default:
      destination = null;
  }

  return SlideLeftRoute(page: destination);
}
```

and this is my Splash page:

```
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulWrapper(
        onInit: () async {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'auth/verify',
                arguments: {'phone': '**********', 'exp': 120});
          });
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Center(child: Text('Splash Screen')
                // child: Text('Splash Screen'),
                ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: @JanviPatel the error caused by TextField , when I remove it, the animation works

Comment: @JanviPatel try again

Comment: @JanviPatel what is your version?

Comment: @JanviPatel the pass is 5t4f6k try again

Comment: @JanviPatel no I use windows I can give you a link to repo

Comment: actually bloc patten is new because i dont use so little bit i need your help so

Comment: @JanviPatel it is open

Comment: @JanviPatel 139750253

Comment: @JanviPatel if I remove the scaffold it works?

Comment: @JanviPatel without scaffold we can't use TextField it throws Ecxeption

Comment: @JanviPatel What should I do exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228622/discussion-between-janvi-patel-and-hadi).